# How to download a generator with Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing an application that generates large amounts of data that the end user will download (CSV files). I currently have a page that generates the data based on entry into a form and returns the created generator object to the user, like so:

```
@app.route('/data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        generator = create_generator(form)
        name = "results.csv"
        return Response(generator, mimetype="text/plain", headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename={}".format(name)})
    return render_template('data.html', title = 'Data Page', form = form)
```

Now, what I would like to do is take that generator, along with some additional data, and pass it to another view/page in the application, so something like:

```
@app.route('/data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        generator, data = create_generator(form)
        name = "results.csv"
        #Can't send data in a redirect, but for example...
        redirect('/result', generator=generator, data=data, name=name)
    return render_template('data.html', title = 'Data Page', form = form)

@app.route('/output', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def output():
    form = Form()
    return render_template('output.html', title = 'Output Page', generator=generator, data=data, name=name)
```

Where `output.html` would then have a clickable link to download the generator. In other words, the generator isn't returned immediately the way it is in the first example with `return Response()`, but instead waits for the user.

To wrap up, the main two things I'm trying to do are:

1. Pass a generator between pages
2. Return a generator as a standard link
   (`<a href={{generator}}></a>` or something like that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP protocol being stateless, what you're asking is undoable. The server doesn't know what you've been doing before you make a request, and the only data attached to a client is the data sent along the request.

A generator is a python object, and as such cannot be integrated in a HTML page or a link as you suggested. You can link to a part of your app that streams a content *using* a generator, but not use a generator as a link, that makes no sense.

The closest you could do is described in the following snippet. There's no actual code written, I just used comments to show you the architecture.

```
@app.route('/data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Complete request
        # Generate data
        # Generate temp filename and save the result in it
        # Display (or redirect to) a page with a link to /get-result/{{ THE RESULT ID }}

    return render_template('data.html', title = 'Data Page', form = form)

@app.route('/get-result/<result_id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def output():
    # Open the result file based on its id
    # Stream it to the client as you did before
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but just wanted to be sure. Thanks!